# SAPUI5 - Data Binding

Tags: odata, sapui5

Anyone knows if is possible, and, how to binding a Control like "ObjectHeader" where the property "Title" is binding from one Entity and the agregations of this control like the ObjectStatus are binding from another Entity.

Here is the code:

```js
bindObjectHeader: function() {

  var objectHeader = this.getView().byId("objectHeader");
  objectHeader.bindElement({
    path: "/Products" 
  });

  objectHeader.bindProperty("title", "Products/ToCategory/Description");
},
```

Well, the Entity **Products** has a *CategoryId* Property, and **ToCategory** is an association between the Entity **Products** and the Entity **Categories**... I want the correspondig *Description* of the given Category and Product

Thank you!

Comment: Is this an OData context? Did you `$expand` the category of your product?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make use of navigation property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483541/how-to-make-use-of-navigation-property)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an entity set which contains multiple entities as described in the JSON object below:

```
var oJson={"rootNode":{
            "node1":[
                     {"name":"myName"}
                    ],
            "node2":[
                     {"age":"15"}
                    ],
            "node3":[
                    {"subnode":"value1"},
                    {"subnode":"value2"},
                    ]
    }};
```

You can create a JSON model and set this data into the model and then set the JSON model at the core as mentioned below:

```
var oModel=new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(oJson);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"myModel");
```

You can now bind the title using one entity and aggregation(statuses) using another entity as described below:

```
var objectHeader=sap.ui.getCore().byId("objectheader");
      var objectStatus=new sap.m.ObjectStatus("objectstatus",{
          title:"{myModel>subnode}"
      });
      objectHeader.bindProperty("title", "myModel>/rootNode/node1/0/name");
      objectHeader.bindAggregation("statuses","myModel>/rootNode/node3",objectStatus);
```

Hope this answer helps you.