# How to make use of navigation property?

Tags: odata, sapui5

An OData service (V2) contains multiple navigation properties as following:

> ```
> ClassNum: "ZPM_TEST_01"
> ClassNumDescr: "ZPM_TEST_01"
> ClassType: "001"
> InternalClass: "0000000130"
> ValidFrom: Tue Sep 04 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
> ValidUntil: Fri Dec 31 9999 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
> to_IClassHeaderVh: {__deferred: {…}}
> to_IClassVh: {__deferred: {…}}
> ```

As you can see above, `to_IClassHeaderVh` and `to_IClassVh` are navigation property.
The code, that requested the OData service:

```js
oModel.read(sUri, {
  success: function (oData) {
  },
  error: Util.showErrorClassNotFound
});
```

How can I get the URL from navigation property via code? I could get it via the object as following:

```js
oData.to_IClassVh.__deferred.uri
```

But I do not know if it is the right way or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigation properties are, as the name suggests, properties with which you can navigate to related entity types. The UI5 framework supports this feature too so that app developers don't have to extract URLs by hand. In fact, you won't even need to call `read`. Let's take this entity data model for example:

<sub><kbd>*CustomerSet*

NavigationProperty: "ToOrders"</kbd></sub>
 <sup><sub>**1**</sub> ___ <sub>**n**</sub></sup> 
<sub><kbd>*OrderSet*

NavigationProperty: "ToCustomer"</kbd></sub>

Navigating from **one entity** to a **collection of entities**:

```xml
<Page><!-- bound to /CustomerSet('ALFKI') -->
  <List items="{ToOrders}">
    <StandardListItem title="{OrderID}" />
  </List>
</Page>
```

Navigating from **one entity** to another **one entity**:

```xml
<Page><!-- bound to /OrderSet(10643) -->
  <Panel binding="{ToCustomer}" headerText="{CustomerName}" />
</Page>
```

The `ODataContextBinding` and `ODataListBinding` will then send requests for you automatically.

---

The `binding` in XML code above is one of the ways to [bind a single entity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280286/5846045).
See also the documentation topic *[Context Binding (Element Binding)](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f05e8b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)*.