# How to use UI5 to $expand (oData) in detail page?

Tags: odata, sapui5

How can i use $expand in detail page, on master detail template in ui5

url (oData):

/Orders?$expand=Products

**List.xml (master)**

```
        <List
            id="orders"
            items="{
                path: 'main>/Orders',
                parameters: {
                    $expand:'Products'
```

**Detail.xml (Detail)**

```
 <List
            id="products"
            items="Products"???
```

how should look like the code on detail xml when i want to show all products related to an order?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546999/5846045 help?